# ¡AYUDA! Como hacer esta consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo estas tablas, planilla, deducciones, bonos, anticipos, empleado, y lo que quiero es sumar el total de bonos, total de deducciones, total de anticipos, luego mostrar estos datos, y con esto calcular el salario total y agruparlo por idEmpleado, lo he hecho con inner join pero me multiplica el resulado casi 60 veces, no se por qué.

[image: Esta es a base de datos]

ESTE ES EL CODIGO QUE TENGO

```
SELECT emp.idEmpleado,
       per.Pnombre PrimerNombre, per.Snombre SegundoNombre, per.Papellido PrimerApellido, per.Sapellido SegundoApellido,
       p.fechaPago, p.montoPago,
       de.estado EstadoDeduccion, de.fecha FechaDeduccion, de.primerMonto PrimerMontoDeduccion,
       bo.estado EstadoBono, bo.pmonto PrimerMontoBono,
       an.estado EstadoAnticipo, an.fecha FechaAnticipo, an.primerMonto PmontoAnticipo,
       ((((SUM(p.montoPago)) + (SUM(bo.pmonto))) - (SUM(de.primerMonto))) - (SUM(an.primerMonto))) total
FROM planilla p
INNER JOIN deducciones de
ON (de.idPlanilla = p.idPlanilla)
INNER JOIN bonos bo
ON (bo.idPlanilla = p.idPlanilla)
INNER JOIN anticipos an
ON (an.idPlanilla = p.idPlanilla)
INNER JOIN empleado emp
ON (emp.idEmpleado = an.idEmpleado)
LEFT JOIN persona per
ON (per.idPersona = emp.idPersona)
group BY emp.idEmpleado
```

Comment: y pq estas agrupando por empleado.. dentro del join... o sea.. como hay miles de fecha de deducciones por ejemplo. no va a traer una sola.. entonces como quieres agrupar realmente?

Comment: @gbianchi Pues realmente quiero agrupar por idEmpleado, para que si el empleado 1 tiene 4 entradas no me salgan las 4 entradas sino que solo me salga 1 entrada con al total de bonos y etc